# How to set Origin domain in React Native?

Tags: react-native, axios, cross-domain

I'm using axios to make network requests in the React Native app. When I build the android/ios app what would the Origin header be? In local dev, before building, it's *localhost:port* but how can I configure it to use my custom domain *"app.mydomain.com"*?

I have to set this to allow CORS in the server running at *"api.mydomain.com"*

Comment: Did you find the answer for this?

Comment: @AshwinMothilal No, I couldn't find how to do it. So I set up my server to accept requests from all origins

Answer (score 1):

Thats how i am using

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://api.domain.com/api";

axios.get("/some/endpoint").then((res) => res.data);
```

Comment: No. I was asking about how to set the origin-http header of the request that the app makes to the api. Not the api's url.